# Where to place a shared utility module in OCaml?

Tags: module, ocaml

I have a file `Tools.ml` which contains some common utility functions I write myself. Under `.../Code/` I have several folders which each contains a project. My question is where I should place this `Tools.ml` such that all the folders and files under `.../Code/` could share this module by `Open Tools`.

Hope my question is clear... Does anyone have a good solution?

**Edit1:** Following @gasche's answer, I have written `tools.ml` as follows:

```
module Tools =
  struct
    let a_function = ...
    ...
  end
```

Then I compiled it, and done `ocamlfind install tools META tools.cmo tools.cmx tools.ml` as suggested, which looks going well. Then I have written `test.ml` as follows:

```
open Tools

let f = Tools.a_function
```

then I compiled it with `ocamlc test.ml -o test`, then I got an error:

```
File "test.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error while linking test.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Tools'
```

Could anyone tell me what happened?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could package it as an independent library, install it with other OCaml libraries, and access to it, from your project, as a library.

A very simple way to do this is to write a META file for `ocamlfind`. Create a directory somewhere you're comfortable to hold you "personal library" project. Suppose you have `tools.ml` and `tools.mli`, and your code depends on some findlib package (eg. `unix` and `bigarray`). You META would look like this:

```
name="tools"
description="personal collection of utilities"
version="0.1"
requires="unix,bigarray"
archive(byte)="tools.cmo"
archive(native)="tools.cmx"
```

Once you have written this META file, it is easy to ask `ocamlfind` to "install" the library (and remove it if you want to), and use it in your other projects. To install, the syntax is `ocamlfind install <name> <meta-file> <file1> <file2> ...` where `<file1>, <file2>..` are the file you wish to see included in the installation directory. You must at least have `tools.cmi` `tools.cmo` (and `tools.o` and `tools.cmx` for native compilation), but it is good practice to also have `tools.mli` for example (and, if you want to provide the code, `tools.ml`).

```
ocamlfind install tools META tools.cmi tools.cmo tools.o tools.cmx tools.mli
```

(Of course `tools.cmo` etc. have to exist, that is you must `install` after you have compiled your package. If you have used `ocamlbuild`, they are likely to be in a `_build` subdirectory, so `ocamlfind install ... _build/tools.cmo ...`.)

From your numerous projects, you can use your library easily, either using the ocamlfind toold directly if this is what you already do to compile your programs

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package tools ....
```

or through the facilities provided by `ocamlbuild` for example, adding `package(tools)` to your tags.

To reinstall your library if you made a change to it and want it accessible from your projects

```
ocamlfind remove tools
ocamlfind install tools META ...
```

You could also handle all this through `oasis`, which is a layer on top of ocamlfind/ocamlbuild to automate this process. I'm not familiar enough with `oasis` to give such examples off the top of my head, but it should be equally simple for such a restricted case (one-file library), and scale better if you wish later to extend your library (eg. it can also handle documentation generation, pre-compilation configuration...).

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Could you please take a look at my test in OP?

Comment: @SoftTimur: the correct compilation command in your case is `ocamlfind ocamlc -package tools -linkpkg test.ml -o test`. The option `-package tools` adds the package, and `-linkpkg` links it to produce an executable (needed when you produce an executable, but not when compiling to a `.cmo`). You could probably also use `ocamlbuild -tag "package(tools)" test.byte` (not tested).

Comment: @gashe: `ocamlfind ocamlc -package tools -linkpkg test.ml -o test` works only when `test.ml` is in the same folder as the executable `tool`... Do you know why?

Comment: Why is `tool` an executable? I thought that was only a library (.ml(i) code meant to be used in other projects). Did you `ocamlfind install ...` the package correctly? Does `ocamlfind list` list the `tools` package?

Comment: I did `ocamlfind install ...` correctly, and `ocamlfind list` does list the `tools` package with the right version. I try to compile a `test.ml` in a folder other than `tools`, it gives `Error: Unbound module Tools`.

Comment: I suppose the META file must be wrong (is the `archive(byte) = foo.cmo` line present?) or the installation incomplete (was `foo.cmo` installed with the META? Is it present in the directory indicated by `ocamlfind query tools`?).

Comment: OK, I got it... the thing is not to forget `tools.cmi` in `ocamlfind install tools META ...`... I do not know if it is better to mention `tools.cmi` in `META`...