# The logic of the ocaml compile process

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I wrote a small project in `OCaml`.

I have two folders:

`./myUnionFind`. inside there is a file `myUnionFind.ml`.

`./percolation`. inside there are two files: `myPercolation.ml` and `percolation_stats.ml`.

---

`myUnionFind.ml` works as a module.

`myPercolation.ml` works as a module too, but it uses `MyUnionFind` module defined in `myUnionFind.ml`.

`percolation_stats.ml` uses `myPercolation.ml`.

together with above all, I also use `Batteries`.

---

I want to compile them all to work and get a executable file `run`.

But **how?**

I have tried the following:

inside folder `./percolation`, I did `ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries -linkpkg ../myUnionFind/myUnionFind.ml myPercolation.ml percolation_stats.ml -o run`

It failed, and said `File "myPercolation.ml", line 1, characters 0-16:
Error: Unbound module MyUnionFind`, but I did include that folder `../myUnionFind`, right?

---

Also, if I just want to compile `./myUnionFind/myUnionFind.ml` once, how can I do so that not every time, `myUnionFind.ml` gets compiled again and again?

Comment: Can you make your code available somewhere? Preferably a git repo. It would make it easier for us to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `myUnionFind`, you should compile `myUnionfind.ml` to a compiled unit:

```
cd myUnionFind
ocamlc -c myUnionFind.ml
```

This will generate `myUnionFind.cmo`, which stores the compiled implementation, and `myUnionFind.cmi`, which stores the compiled *interface*. Other modules using `MyUnionFind` will need to access the `cmi` at type-checking type.

Inside percolation, you can compile myPercolation.ml to a module by doing

cd percolation
   ocamlc -I ../myUnionFind -c myPercolation.ml

Again, you get both a .cmo and a .cmi. Note that the compiler has looked up myUnionFind.cmi automatically in the search path, and found it because of the `-I` option.

You can then compile `percolation_stats` (relying on both previous compilation units)

```
ocamlc -I ../myUnionFind -c percolation_stats.ml
```

You finally link the three resulting .cmo together to build an executable:

```
ocamlc ../myUnionFind.cmo myPercolation.cmo percolation_stats.cmo -o run
```

(If you use batteries, wrap each command with `ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries`, but only the linking command with `linkpkg`).

To make this process simpler:

- `ocamlbuild` is good at finding and compiling all the files of your current project to produce an executable. In the `percolation` directory, `ocamlbuild percolation_stats.byte` can produce an executable with all the stuff present
- but if you want to use `myUnionFind` as an external library, the best thing to do would be to install it with `findlib`, to make it easy to find and specify from `percolation`; for information on how to create a findlib package (it's very simple), please see [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665591/298143)
- once myUnionFind is a findlib package, the single command `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs batteries,my-union-find percolation_stats.byte` (or `.native`) should be enough to get an executable

Comment: what do you mean by `but only the linking command with linkpkg`?

Comment: You don't need to tell `-linkpkg` to ocamlfind before (when producing compilation units), only at the linking step of producing the final executable.

Comment: ok. what if I want to compile three files together as they all have been changed? instead of compile one by one?

Comment: write a script or use a build tool? Some steps can be skipped, but I don't remember precisely which right now. Try the command you gave with all `.ml`, adding the missing `-I` option.

Note that `myPercolation` doesn't need to be recompiled if `myUnionFind` changed but not its interface (so not its `.cmi`); you can link the new `myUnionFind.cmo` with the old other `.cmo` into a final executable. Separate compilation for the win.