# How can I write a library in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I am writing a bson encoder/decoder library in ocaml.

I have the source file now (actually just one file).

My question is that how should I make it as a library, such as `ocaml-batteries-included`, `camomile`, etc?

I mean, people can use `opam install` it and use `ocamlfind` + `ocamlbuild` to compile with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supporting `ocamlfind` is really easy, and there is no excuse not to do it. Basically, pick any "similar" library, look for the META file, and adapt it to your own setting. I have given some basic instructions in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665591/298143).

OCamlbuild is a build system that you are free to decide to use or not, but should not impact your users (besides the fact that they will to install it before building your programs). You may also use a Makefile or any other build system (omake, etc.). The idea of ocamlbuild is just to provide a `_tags` file with sufficient information to build your library/program (and if you're doing advanced stuff a `myocamlbuild.ml` file as well). Again, look at what projects that have a structure similar to yours are doing.

For Opam, there is a [packaging guide](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/doc/Packaging.html) to give your directions (but again, just adapt what other people are doing).

Answer (score 2):

I will pitch something that is a little non standard but entirely usable: [obuild](https://github.com/vincenthz/obuild). All you need is a `project.obuild` file and then `obuild build` will build your project. `obuild install` will install it with ocamlfind.

Install obuild from github instead of opam however since the opam version is a little out of date. Here's a sample `obuild` file to give you an idea: https://github.com/vbmithr/ocaml-websocket/blob/master/websocket.obuild

Comment: it seems like ocaml-websocket is using oasis with ocamlbuild …

Answer (score 1):

Go for [Oasis](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/); you basically create a file `_oasis` that describes your library. The `oasis` tool will then create a build system for you. You can install Oasis via [Opam](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/).
There is a [quick start](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/quickstart.html) tutorial for Oasis that will get you started.

Oasis is an effort to standardize a computer readable description of OCaml packages. And while at it, it can create the build system as a by-product (currently an `ocamlbuild` based one and Makefiles are supported).