# Ocamlfind installed my own lib but still `Unbound module` when using my lib

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

My lib has two files: `bson.ml` and `bson.mli`.

I also have another test file which use `let doc = Bson.make ();;` etc to access the library and it is fine without any problem.

I also successfully build them and I get `bson.cmx` and `bson.cmo`

---

I then followed [Where to place a shared utility module in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663869/where-to-place-a-shared-utility-module-in-ocaml/8665591#8665591) for `ocamlfind install`.

The META is like this:

```
name="bson"
description="A bson data structure, including encoding/decoding"
version="0.88.1"
archive(byte)="bson.cmo"
archive(native)="bson.cmx"
```

---

As instructed from the post above, the command I used is

`ocamlfind install bson META _build/src/bson.cmx _build/src/bson.cmo src/bson.mli`

It said

```
Removed /Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson
Installed /Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson/bson.mli
Installed /Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson/bson.cmo
Installed /Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson/bson.cmx
Installed /Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson/META
```

---

If I use `ocamlfind list`, I can see it is there

```
bisect              (version: 1.3)
bson                (version: 0.88.1)
camlp4              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
```

---

ok, then I open `ocaml toplevel` and `#require "bson"`. It said

```
# #require "bson";;
/Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson: added to search path
/Users/xxx/.opam/4.00.1/lib/bson/bson.cmo: loaded
```

---

finally, when I begin to use it `let doc = Bson.make ();;`, it sayd **Error: Unbound module Bson**.

**Why?**

**I successfully installed my lib, why still can not use it?**

**Edit**

I also tried load it via command line such as `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package bson test.native`, still does not work

Comment: whoever downvote or close this, please give a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out by myself.

I should also install the `.cmi` and `.o` files. If without `.o` file, native cannot be compiled.

I should use `ocamlfind install bson META _build/src/bson.cmx _build/src/bson.cmo  src/bson.mli _build/src/bson.cmi _build/src/bson.o`

instead of `ocamlfind install bson META _build/src/bson.cmx _build/src/bson.cmo src/bson.mli`

i.e., add **_build/src/bson.cmi _build/src/bson.o** (Please see @gasche's comment below)

Comment: You *must* install the `.cmi`, without wich the type-checker is not able to know what the module interface is, but you *should* also install the `.mli` for documentation purposes.

Sorry for the error-inducing answer to the other post (I wrote the commands from memory without testing them); I edited it to correct the installation command.