# (OCamlfind) build library with dependencies to Core

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind, omake

I'm trying to build a small library that has dependencies to Core and Core_extended. I followed the instructions under [Where to place a shared utility module in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663869/where-to-place-a-shared-utility-module-in-ocaml/8665591#8665591) and installed the library in ocamlfind (declaring a dependency to Core_extended and Core in the META-file).
Using it in the top-level works fine now.

However, when I try to build a test-file using this library, it doesn't detect the dependencies to Core and Core_extend automatically. Using these compile instructions

> ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -g -package my_lib -thread -o file.cmx file.ml
>
> ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -linkpkg -package my_lib -thread file.cmx -o file.native

I get the following error:

> Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
>
> ```
>    Core referenced from /.../mylib.cmx
>
>    Core_extended referenced from /.../mylib.cmx
> ```

If I compile the file using the extra arguments "-package core_extended" then it compiles, however this is quite impractical.

Is there a way to make this dependency transparent to the compilation-process, such that "-package my_lib" automatically loads in Core and Core_extended?

EDIT:
This is the content of my META-file:

```
name="my_lib"
description="small library"
version="0.1"
depends="core,core_extended"
archive(byte)="my_lib.cmo"
archive(native)="my_lib.cmx"
```

EDIT2:

Renaming "depends" to "requires" in the META-file fixed this!

Comment: Can you show META file for your library?

Comment: added the META-file in the edit

Comment: I'm not sure does it matter but all METAs on my machines use `requires` instead of `depends`

Answer (score 1):

You should write `requires` instead of `depends`